# Bind input and select change without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Im wanting to bind `input` and `select` changes without `jQuery`.

Currently i have the following in `jQuery`

```
$(':input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
});
$('select').each(function(){
    var Selected = $(this).children('option:selected');
    $(this).children('option').removeAttr('selected', false);
    Selected.attr('selected', true);
    $(this).replaceWith($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
$(':input').bind('keyup', function() {
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
});
$('select').change(function(){
    var Selected = $(this).children('option:selected');
    $(this).children('option').removeAttr('selected', false);
    Selected.attr('selected', true);
    $(this).replaceWith($(this)[0].outerHTML);
    $('select').unbind('change');
    $('select').change(function(){
        var Selected = $(this).children('option:selected');
        $(this).children('option').removeAttr('selected', false);
        Selected.attr('selected', true);
        $(this).replaceWith($(this)[0].outerHTML);
        $('select').unbind('change');
    });
});
```

How could this be done withou `jQuery`?

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` to find all the elements matching a selector, and `addEventListener` to bind the event handler.

Comment: This could be a combination of .getElementsByTagName + addEventListener.

Answer (score 2):

It's a question of knowing the native equivalents to jQuery shortcuts. So:

```
$(':input') //jQuery
document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea, button'); //native
```

And for jQuery's `.bind()`, `.change()`, `.on()` or any other of its various event binding methods, there's `.addEventListener()` in native.

So you just have to put them together. Grab all the elements, loop over them and bind to each of them:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea, button');
[].forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    this.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        //do something on key up
    }, false);
    if (el.tagName == 'SELECT') this.addEventListener('change', function() {
        //also do something on change for dropdowns
    }, false);
});
```